# nodejs mysql table with a lot of columns to dynamically update

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a table in mysql with a lot of columns to update dynamically.

The front end is passing an object like this:

```
  "columns2update": 
  [{ name: "column1", val: "Y" },
  { name: "column4", val: "Y" },
  { name: "column5", val: "Y" },
  { name: "column8", val: "Y" },
  { name: "column12", val: "Y" },
  { name: "column22", val: "Y" },
  { name: "column43", val: "Y" },
  { name: "column55", val: "Y" },
  { name: "column76", val: "Y" },
  { name: "column85", val: "Y" }]
```

Object will be different depending on what columns has been selected.

How do I loop thru this object? Update the columns in the object name: ? A stored proc would be best if possible.

It would be terrible to pass all the columns names to update just a few columns.

```
   mysqlPool.getConnection(function(error,conn){

        conn.query("SET @p1 = 53; SET @p2 = 20; SET @p3 = 0; SET @p4 = 15; CALL PROC_NAME( @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)", function(error,results)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            }else{
                console.log(results);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used brute force to fix this issue. I will find an elegant solutions later. Its actually fast but the code maintenance will be an issue.